# Cookie dependent applications

Tags: cookies

What will be the situation if the application is dependent on cookies and user turned off cookies in browser?

Will the application fail to run?
Do developers need to handle it differently when cookies are turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what your Application should do,
there is always an O-Point e.g. your are online at Facebook
and you start a new window in private mode you will not logged in.
Because the Cookie holds the session (cookie holds serveral informations)
I hope I could help you with it a bit tell me if I missed the topic

Comment: I'm developing an application and need to store some session information at client side. Read through many articles related to "local storage vs cookies" and both have their own pros and cons. Cookies seem to having higher advantage. But I got this doubt on handling the situation when Cookies are turned off by the user.

Comment: You can block your website if the user disabled cookies, then you can implement an pop-up that to ask the user to allow cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The app wont fail to run, but developers have to handle the situation differently when cookies are turned off.

For example, Facebook displays publicities related to your cookie informations. If you were looking for X product on Amazon, it will then display pubs about it.

If cookies are disabled, it would display other pubs, it wouldn't crash.